# How to get the ID of <asp:TextBox>?

Tags: asp.net, textbox

For example I got a `<asp:FormView>` and there are IDs inside. Why is that I can't get one of the ID inside the `<asp:FormView>`, the error shows as "**The name 'commentsLabel' does not exist in the current context**"

How to get the ID of one of the `<asp:TextBox>` that is inside `<asp:FormView>` ?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you show a bit more code of the ASPX page?

Comment: please specify where do you want to get the id of the textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question isn't very clear, but I suppose this is what you have:

```
<asp:FormView runat="server" ID="aFormView">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="commentsLabel"/>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

and you want to access `commentsLabel` in the code behind of the control/page on which you have this markup.

Since `FormView` is a naming container, you can find the controls inside it like this:

```
Label commentsLabel = (Label)aFormView.FindControl("commentsLabel");
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do that by `FindControl` method

try this

```
TextBox t = MyFormView.FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox;
String textBoxID = t.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

If textbox is accessible on page it is very simple to get its ID. Might be you are doing mistake somewhere.

ForExample:
I have a textbox and label

```
  <asp:Label ID="lblCode" runat="server" Text="Code"></asp:Label>
  <asp:TextBox ID="tbCode" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Their IDs can be easily accessible...

```
        string ID = tbCode.ID;
        string LableID = lblCode.ID;
```

If you can explain your question little more than we can help you in right direction..